# Lighting mismatch in "All the Money in the World"

Tags: film-techniques, lighting, all-the-money-in-the-world

Was this scene from [*All the Money in the World*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5294550/) shot with green screen? Or any way of combining two different shots?

[image]

I feel like the light on the subjects doesn't match the background, I can't decide if it's natural light or due to post-production.

Comment: If you look carefully you can just see the ghost of Kevin Spacey behind him;) Yes, afaik, all the Plummer shots are green-screened & combined in post [but I don't have a direct citation for that particular shot]

Comment: @Tetsujin I don’t think that’s right. Recent articles about the controversy over how much Wahlberg got paid for reshoots say they went to Rome, so at least some of the reshot scenes were done on location and not green screened.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about it, that's why I can't make up my mind about this scene. The only scenes with green screen should be those in the desert, 'cause it was impossible to reshoot them on location. This one should have been reshot, but the lighting seems weird to me... I think it could be a composite shot, but wanted opinions from someone else about it.

Comment: Pure opinion... unless you find someone was actually there, you'll never know. There's no reason that has to be natural light. It could be a set, completely artificially lit & you would never be able to tell. Natural light through windows like that really isn't strong or consistent enough to be reliable. A sheet of diffuser & a big 12k lamp outside the window is much easier to work with, even if it's a real building.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right, I shouldn't have said "natural light", I meant just light used on set and not due to post-production of any sort. Fact is, if it's just artificially lit but still shot on location, I don't think they did a very good job with the lights. It's just a personal opinion, but I can't help but notice how much the subjects come out, it feels fake to me.